# Efficiently Handling Large Number of API Calls with Delphi 10.4 and OmniThreadLibrary

Tags: multithreading, rest, delphi, threadpool, omnithreadlibrary

I'm seeking advice on efficiently managing a significant number of background tasks in Delphi 10.4, utilizing the OmniThreadLibrary.

Specifically, I aim to handle around 500 tasks for computation purposes. To prevent these tasks from consuming all system resources, I'd like to limit the number of concurrent threads (e.g., 5, 10, 15). Additionally, I want to ensure that once one task completes processing, another task starts until all tasks are finished.

I would appreciate any guidance, examples, or suggestions on effectively achieving this objective using Delphi and OmniThreadLibrary. Thank you for your assistance!

I explored the possibility of using the scheduling mechanism, but it didn't yield a satisfactory solution.

Comment: One one thread finishes, I want to start another thread. That sounds like a serial algorithm. So threads are pointless and will make things much worse.

Comment: It is inefficient to create 3000 threads. It is sufficient to have 5 threads, which process 600 API calls each.

Comment: I think you could achieve what you want by using OMNIThred's `ParallelTask abstract` or `ForEach abstract`, in conjunction with `OtThreadPool` in order to limit of how many threads can be used at the same time.